# How to get the total number of Flash Messages in Laravel Session::Flash

Tags: php, laravel

I want to know the total number of Session Flash messages.

I have looked through the `Illuminate\Session\Store.php` to see if there was some sort of `count()` method. But I didn't see one.

Is this even possible?

I ask because I want to create a "Notifications Area" with a badge to show how many message are in the Session.

```
  <li class="header">You have {{SESSION_COUNT_HERE}} notifications</li>
```

The below works for outputting a single message type, but I want to also loop though each individual session message and display them all.

```
  @foreach (['danger', 'warning', 'success', 'info'] as $msg)
     @if(Session::has($msg))
       <li>
         <a href="#"> {{ Session::get($msg) }} </a>
       </li>
     @endif
  @endforeach
```

If I were to do something like this and add multiple messages. Only one success message is stored. I am guessing there is no array of sessions messages?

```
        Session::flash('success', 'This is a success 1 test');
        Session::flash('success', 'This is a success 2 test');
        Session::flash('success', 'This is a success 3 test');
        Session::flash('warning', 'This is a  warning test');
        Session::flash('danger', 'This is a  danger test');
        Session::flash('info', 'This is a info test');

        dd(session());
```

The output shows

```
#session: Illuminate\Session\Store {#270 ▼
            #id: ""
            #name: "laravel_session"
            #attributes: array:7 [▼
              "_token" => ""
              "_previous" => array:1 [▼
                "url" => "http://mysite.dev"
              ]
              "_flash" => array:2 [▼
                "old" => []
                "new" => array:6 [▼
                  0 => "success"
                  1 => "success"
                  2 => "success"
                  3 => "warning"
                  4 => "danger"
                  5 => "info"
                ]
              ]
              "success" => "This is a success 3 test"
              "warning" => "This is a  warning test"
              "danger" => "This is a  danger test"
              "info" => "This is a info test"
            ]
```

While the key property 'new' shows the correct count, there is actually only the last success message.